# issue implementing Angular material in a angular library

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am implementing  MatDatePicker but I have this visual issue with this component:
[image: issue matdatepicker]

My library code : [My code](https://github.com/Crisfon6/ngx-components-lib-cf6/tree/main/projects/ngx-components-lib-cf6)

https://github.com/Crisfon6/ngx-components-lib-cf6/tree/main/projects/ngx-components-lib-cf6The implementation is this:

(https://github.com/Crisfon6/ngx-components-lib-cf6/tree/main/projects/ngx-components-lib-cf6)

This is the same example of the page of angular material

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'lib-mat-datepicker',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatFormFieldModule, MatDatepickerModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, JsonPipe
  ],
  providers: [provideNativeDateAdapter(),provideAnimations()],
  template: `
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
  <mat-date-range-input [formGroup]="range" [rangePicker]="picker">
    <input matStartDate formControlName="start" placeholder="Start date">
    <input matEndDate formControlName="end" placeholder="End date">
  </mat-date-range-input>
  <mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY – MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>

  @if (range.controls.start.hasError('matStartDateInvalid')) {
    <mat-error>Invalid start date</mat-error>
  }
  @if (range.controls.end.hasError('matEndDateInvalid')) {
    <mat-error>Invalid end date</mat-error>
  }
</mat-form-field>

<p>Selected range: {{range.value | json}}</p>
  `,
  styleUrl: './matDatepicker.component.css'
})
export class MatDatepickerComponent {
  range = new FormGroup({
    start: new FormControl<Date | null>(null),
    end: new FormControl<Date | null>(null),
  });
 }
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing the CSS theme. Did you install with `ng add @angular/material`? https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Comment: Yes, I did this for add angular material to my project

Comment: Do you mean the command failed?

Comment: The command executes correctly, I can even import the modules from the angular material library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a theme for angular material in the angular.json

```
   "styles": [
          "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
```

I was testing out an when i erased the "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" the date picker it looked like yours.